# API React many objects

Tags: reactjs, api, axios, react-typescript

I need to display many information from API returns.
It looks like this:

```
{
"success": true,
"data": {
    "favourite_conseils": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "title": "Title 1",
            "speciality": [],
            "attachments": [],
            "isFavourite": true,
            "isPack": false,
            "message": "Message conseil 1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."
        }
    ],
    "suggested_conseils": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "title": "Title 2",
            "speciality": [
                1
            ],
            "attachments": [],
            "isFavourite": false,
            "isPack": false,
            "message": "Message conseil 2. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."
        }
    ],
    "specialities": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "blabla",
            "label": "Blabla"
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to take `favorite_conseils` and display all (here have just one) and make seems with `suggested_conseils`
Actually, I have tutorials, setTutorials and I make response.data (from axios return) in tutorials variable. But I can't use `.map` because the first value is an object, not an array...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You can view my component here :
https://controlc.com/e9e7e77f
I need to use retrieveTutorials first

Answer (score 0):

You can use `response.data.favourite_conseils` to set favourite_conseils and similar for suggested_conseils and other. After that you can use map function,

Comment: Yes but when I use console.log from response.data.favorite_conseils he say me "Property 'favorite_conseils' does not exist on type 'never'." and I cant compile my app...

Comment: Try putting null check like response?.data?.favourite_conseils

That should work

Comment: Seems problem when I add "?", doesnt exist

Comment: Share  your code snippet here

Comment: Yes :
const retrieveTutorials = () => { TutorialDataService.getAll() .then(response => { console.log(response?.data?.favorite_conseils); setTutorials(response.data); }) .catch(e => { console.log(e); }); };
 I use axios like this for call API : 
const getAll = () => { return http.get("/conseils/default_conseils"); };
(the link and header with login token is is other file)

Comment: what is the error ?
Try 
.then((response:any)=> console.log(response?.data?.favourite_conseils)

Comment: Its ok with response.any, dont have error but console say me "undefined"

Comment: That means you are not getting response from API.

Comment: If I make console.log(response.data) I can read the response from API, data.favorite_conseils it's just a variable that doesn't exist so it doesn't show it to me.

Comment: Try like response.data["favourite_conseils"]

or share the output of resposne.data which is in console

Comment: response.data["favourite_conseils"] undefined always. response.data is already shared in topic but you can also see here : [https://controlc.com/00af3103](https://controlc.com/00af3103)

Comment: Oh its ok ! Its in response.data.data.favourite_conseils (i need to write 2 .data)
Sorry..... and thanks you !